# One shop different view domains

Tags: magento, hyperlink, dns, view

I'm taking magneto courses and I got this exercise I can't crack. I have these stores and store views(adding pick) !
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hB1pU.jpg)

So basicaly what i need to do is to make separate links for each view but domain must be same for each. (i.e. www.domain.com for "OdiniaiBatai", www.domain.com/guminiai_batai for "GuminiaiBatai", www.domain.com/laikrodziai for "Laikrodziai" and so on.) views must also be different when you click each link. Can someone help me i'm really stuck with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `System->Configuration->Web->Url Options` and set the field `Add Store Code to Urls` to `Yes`. Save and clear the cache.